# Disable a href after click once and add new element at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it posible to add new element with javascript by using href and disable href at the same time?
So href only clicked once, and after that the new element will appear.
I wrote this code, but still no luck

***JS***

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $("#add_app").click(function() {
   $("#box").append("<p>jQuery is Amazing...</p>"); 
   this.removeAttribute('href');this.className='disabled';
 }});
```

***HTML***

```
<a href="#" id="add_app" ><strong>Summon new element and disable me</strong></a>
```

The only does the job is in JS line

```
$("#box").append("<p>jQuery is Amazing...</p>");
```

Need help..
Thanks

--------------------------------------UPDATE---------------------------------
-Using improved code by PacMan, Linus Aronsson, and guest271314 and it works like a charm.
So basically we use .one() event handler to solve the problem.
Thanks for the feedback guys

Comment: You must not edit your question with the solution, you must upvote and accept the correct answer. That's how this community works and why the people help you for free.

Comment: Thanks for the correction Marcos Pérez Gude, edited by adding acceptance answer. But i don't have enough reputation for upvote.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, you will learn something new every days. When you have enough reputation you can upvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#add_app").one("click", function() {
    $("#box").append("<p>jQuery is Amazing...</p>"); 
    this.removeAttribute('href');
  });
});
```

I'm using the .one() event handler to indicate that you only want the click event to take place once. The rest of the code was more or less correct with a few small changes.

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0mobshpr/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.one()`; note `js` at Question is missing closing parenthesis `)` at `click()`

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#add_app").one("click", function() {
     $("#box").append("<p>jQuery is Amazing...</p>"); 
     this.removeAttribute('href');this.className='disabled';
   })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

**HTML**

```
<a style="cursor: pointer;"  id="add_app" ><strong>Summon new element and disable me</strong></a>
<div id="box"></div>
```

and in your JS code you can write this i have tested it and it worked fine

```
$(function(){
  $("#add_app").one("click",function(){
    $("#box").append("<p>jQuery is Amazing...</p>");
  });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to return false whwn the link is click.
try this one JQuery code..

```
$("#add_app").click(function() {
   $("#box").append("<p>jQuery is Amazing...</p>");
   return false;
});
```